# Information Technology being evolved since ... or started to evolve since ...?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I can not to choose combination of words in right form and tense to write about development (in meaning progress, evolution) of Information Technology.

So, I want to write consistently two things:

1) Information Technology **started to evolve since** 1960s. (I guess here should be used passive voice and other tense like being + V3)

2) Then in 1990s **as** the Internet **appeared**, IT **began to evolve more rapidly**. (unlike it was earlier)

P.S. Can I change "evolve" with "develop" ?

Answer (score 2):

> Information Technology started to evolve since 1960s. (I guess here should be used passive voice and other tense like being + V3)

You should say "IT began developing in the 1960s"

> Then in 1990s as the Internet appeared, IT began to evolve more rapidly. (unlike it was earlier)

You should say "Then, in the 1990s, when the Internet appeared, IT began to develop even more rapidly."

You should omit the

> (unlike it was earlier)

Because it's implied by the previous passage.

Also, this is from a technical standpoint, but the Internet was not developed in the 90s. The World Wide Web was developed in the 90s.

Comment: thanx a lot. I really used to think that IT (Information Technology) is developed (evolved) by people not by his own. So, I used to think that verb "develop" with a noun "Information Technology" should be used in passive voice.

Another thanx for you made this question clear for me.